# Oracle SQL elegant way of decoding regexp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

| MATERIAL |
| --- |
| ESMART_1ELE_ADE |
| ELEC_SMETS1_CREDIT |
| ESMART_1ELE_ALCS |
| GAS-METER-PREPAY |
| ELEC_SMETS1 |

What would be the most elegant way of obtaining a column which, if the row contains either the string 'SMART' or 'SMETS', outputs 'S' else 'D'?

| MATERIAL | EXPECTED_OUTPUT |
| --- | --- |
| ESMART_1ELE_ADE | S |
| ELEC_SMETS1_CREDIT | S |
| ESMART_1ELE_ALCS | S |
| GAS-METER-PREPAY | D |
| ELEC_SMETS1 | S |

Code to get the first table:

```
WITH aux ( material ) AS (
    SELECT
        'ESMART_1ELE_ADE'
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'ELEC_SMETS1_CREDIT'
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'ESMART_1ELE_ALCS'
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'GAS-METER-PREPAY'
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'ELEC_SMETS1'
    FROM
        dual
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    aux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'SMART' or 'SMETS', outputs 'S' else 'D'?

I would use `like`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when material like '%SMART%' or material like '%SMETS%'
             then 'S' else 'D'
        end)
from aux a;
```

However, `regexp_like()` is more concise:

```
select a.*,
       (case when regexp_like(material, 'SMART|SMETS')
             then 'S' else 'D'
        end)
from aux a;
```